How to install .NET Core console app on Windows to get executed directly from command prompt
I have developed simple .NET Core 8.0 console application (app name: opengate.exe). To run this app, I have to locate the folder first on the command prompt then I can run the opengate.exe.
I want this application should also be runnable directly from C:\> when user just type my exe name on command prompt for example
C:\>opengate

As of now user always needs to locate the exe first with the complete path then only it can.
Example
C:\MyApps\opengateApp> opengate

This facility I required to make the application usage user-friendly so that any user who has access on the server just need to go on command prompt and can execute the opengate console app, rather first to locate the application on the local server path then execute that.
Do we have any application package builder in Visual Studio 2022 that can install the console application on windows and get that accessible using C:\> directly or any other way to get it done?

Add the path to the exe in the PATH environment variable

First, you can manually modify the environment variables and add your target path to the system environment variables. In this way, you can directly enter opengate in the command prompt and the application can run directly.
I created a C# console application, used the AddToSystemPath method, and completed the test, which can also accomplish this.
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string newPath = @"your target path";
       AddToSystemPath(newPath);
   }
 
   static void AddToSystemPath(string path)
   {
       const string environmentKey = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";
       const string pathValueName = "Path";
 
       using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(environmentKey, writable: true))
       {
           string currentPath = (string)key.GetValue(pathValueName, string.Empty);
 
           if (!currentPath.Split(';').Contains(path, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               string newPath = currentPath + ";" + path;
               key.SetValue(pathValueName, newPath);
 
               Console.WriteLine("Path updated successfully.");
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Path already exists in system environment variables.");
           }
       }
 
       // Notify the system about the environment variable change (This part plays an important role and is indispensable. I have tried to delete it, but the system cannot recognize it even if the path is added, and the specified file cannot be called directly.)
 
       NotifySystemAboutEnvironmentChange();
   }
 
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   private static extern bool SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out IntPtr lpdwResult);
 
   private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF;
   private const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
   private const uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
 
   private static void NotifySystemAboutEnvironmentChange()
   {
       IntPtr result;
       SendMessageTimeout(new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto("Environment"), SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, out result);
   }
}

NotifySystemAboutEnvironmentChange
This part plays an important role and is indispensable. I have tried to delete it, but the system cannot recognize it even if the path is added, and the specified file cannot be called directly.
After running, you can check the environment variables and you will find that your target path has been successfully added.
